# jq ~ is there a better way to collapse single object arrays?

Tags: json, jq

**Question:**
Is this the best way to do this ?

Tool:

`jq --version
jq-1.5-1-a5b5cbe`

**Requirement:**  To recursively identify arrays `[]` that only contain a single object `{}` and to convert the array back to a standard object `{}`.  Essentially to strip out the parent array when its not needed.

**What seems to be working:**

`(..|select(type=="array" and .[1] == null ) | . ) |= add | .`

**Use case:**
Google Custom Search JSON contains numerous arrays, many of which are single object arrays.  Logstash `input`, `codec => json` and/or `json` filter seems not to be able to automatically turn single object arrays into elasticsearch fields.

Comment: To test whether an array has length 1, you cannot rely on the test `.[1]==null` as the second element might be null.  There are other problems with your "What seems to be working" program as well.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach is to use `walk/1`, which however was only introduced after the release of jq 1.5.  The following therefore includes its definition:

```
# Apply f to composite entities recursively, and to atoms
def walk(f): 
  . as $in
  | if type == "object" then
      reduce keys[] as $key
        ( {}; . + { ($key):  ($in[$key] | walk(f)) } ) | f
  elif type == "array" then map( walk(f) ) | f
  else f
  end;

walk(if type=="array" and length==1 and (.[0]|type) == "object" then .[0] else . end)
```

Of course many variants are possible, e.g. along the lines of your program:

```
walk(if type=="array" and length==1 then .[0] else . end)
```