# R: Nested data.table to JSON

Tags: r, json, nested, data.table

I want to get from a data.table like this

```
temp <- data.table(data = list(data.table(a = 1:2,b=1:2)), type = "A")
```

| data | type |
| --- | --- |
| <data.table[2x2]> | A |

to a JSON like this

```
{
    "group": 
      {
        "data": [
          {
            "a": 1,
            "b": 1
          },
          {
            "a": 2,
            "b": 2
          }
        ],
        "type": "A"
      }
  }
```

The Problem is I always end up with an additional array "[" for group.
What I have tried is tidyr::nest and

```
temp2 <- temp[, list(group=list(.SD))]
jsonlite::toJSON(temp2,pretty = TRUE, auto_unbox = TRUE)

temp3 <- temp[, (list(group=list(as.list(.SD))))]
jsonlite::toJSON(temp3,pretty = TRUE, auto_unbox = TRUE)
```

Is there an "easy" solution for my problem?
Thanks

*edit more complex example*

```
temp <-
  data.table(
    id1 = 1:6,
    id2 = c(rep("A", 2), rep("B", 2), rep("C", 2)),
    data = rep(list(data.table(
      a = 1:2, b = 1:2
    )), 6),
    type = "test"
  )

nest1 <-  temp[, list(list(.SD)),by=.(id1,id2)] %>% setnames("V1","group")
nest1[, type:="B"]
nest2 <-  nest1[, list(list(.SD)),by=.(id2)] %>% setnames("V1","data")
nest2[, type:="C"]
nest3 <- nest2[, list(list(.SD)),by=.(id2)] %>% setnames("V1","group")

jsonlite::toJSON(nest3, pretty = TRUE)
```

desired output (shortend):
Group should only contain objects and no arrays

```
[
  {
    "id2": "A",
    "group": {
        "data": [
          {
            "id1": 1,
            "group": {
                "data": [
                  {
                    "a": 1,
                    "b": 1
                  },
                  {
                    "a": 2,
                    "b": 2
                  }
                ],
                "type": "test"
              },
            "type": "B"
          },
          {
            "id1": 2,
            "group": {
                "data": [
                  {
                    "a": 1,
                    "b": 1
                  },
                  {
                    "a": 2,
                    "b": 2
                  }
                ],
                "type": "test"
              },
            "type": "B"
          }
        ],
        "type": "C"
      }
  },
  {
    "id2": "B",
    "group": {
        "data": [],
        "type": "C"
      }
  }
]
```

Comment: `jsonlite::toJSON(list("group" = temp), pretty = TRUE, auto_unbox = TRUE)`

Comment: Nice idea thanks, but the result is still the same as above. I end up with the additional array.
Additionally, the example is just a small part of the complete nested structure.

Comment: Got it. For some reason we need to manually unbox the data.frame. The documentation is a bit ambiguous in this regard IMO: `auto_unbox` only mentions atomic vectors, while `unbox()` also unboxes data frames of 1 row, so it's not literally applying `unbox()` automatically. Anyway: `jsonlite::toJSON(list(group = jsonlite::unbox(temp)), pretty = TRUE, auto_unbox = TRUE)` should do it

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solutions works for my example. Unfortunately I'm not able to use it for my real problem. 1) The data.table consists of several rows `temp <- data.table(data = list(data.table(a = 1:2,b=1:2),data.table(a=2:3,b=3:4)), type = c("A","B"))` and is further nested. I have several group objects on different levels.

Do I have to make single JSON files from each object and combine them?

Comment: Can you make the question more general, with a more complex example and desired output?

Comment: I've edited a more complex example in my first post

Comment: Note on the desired output: looks like invalid JSON. `"group"` would have to be an array. (Well, the several instances of `"group"`). Can be checked with e.g. jsonlint.com

Comment: You are right, of course. The example is not correct... Let me fix it. I'm sorry

Comment: I've updated the example to a correct JSON. Once again I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use `jq` to do the unboxing as a post-processing step, since `jsonlite` doesn't seem to allow for this specific use case:

```
jsonlite::toJSON(nest3, pretty = TRUE) %>% 
  jqr::jq('walk(if type=="array" and length==1 then .[0] else . end)')
```

The `jq` bit is taken from [jq ~ is there a better way to collapse single object arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51157550/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Didn't knew about this package.
Works like a charm for my specific example. 
One last question though. How do I make it specific for the "group" elements. In this case if "data" has only one object it is also reduced to an object, but it needs to stay there as an array.
Something like  `jqr::jq('walk(if .group and type=="array"  and length==1  then .[0] else . end)')`

Comment: Good point. I came up with `.... %>% jqr::jq('walk(if type=="object"  and has("group")  
 and (.group | type)=="array"   and (.group | length)==1   then .group = .group[0]   else . end)')` but I'm no jq pro.