# jq ~ collapse specific single object arrays?

Tags: json, group-by, jq

corresponding to [jq ~ is there a better way to collapse single object arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51157550/jq-is-there-a-better-way-to-collapse-single-object-arrays) and [R: Nested data.table to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70016854/r-nested-data-table-to-json)
how do I collapse only specific elements?

I want to get rid of the "group" arrays in

```
[
  {
    "id2": "A",
    "group": [
      {
        "data": [
          {
            "id1": 1,
            "group": [
              {
                "data": [
                  {
                    "a": 1,
                    "b": 1
                  },
                  {
                    "a": 2,
                    "b": 2
                  }
                ],
                "type": "test"
              }
            ],
            "type": "B"
          }
        ],
        "type": "C"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id2": "C",
    "group": [
      {
        "data": [
          {
            "id1": 3,
            "group": [
              {
                "data": [
                  {
                    "a": 1,
                    "b": 1
                  }
                ],
                "type": "test"
              }
            ],
            "type": "B"
          }
        ],
        "type": "C"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

desired output

```
[{
        "id2": "A",
        "group": {
            "data": [{
                "id1": 1,
                "group": {
                    "data": [{
                            "a": 1,
                            "b": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "a": 2,
                            "b": 2
                        }
                    ],
                    "type": "test"
                },
                "type": "B"
            }],
            "type": "C"
        }
    },
    {
        "id2": "C",
        "group": {
            "data": [{
                "id1": 3,
                "group": {
                    "data": [{
                        "a": 1,
                        "b": 1
                    }],
                    "type": "test"
                },
                "type": "B"
            }],
            "type": "C"
        }
    }
]
```

The line  `'walk(if type=="array" and length==1  then .[0] else . end)'` additionally removes the array from the single "data" object.

---

Unfortunately, we are not able to install the jq 1.6 version on our RStudio Server und thereby I'm not able to use the walk function. (Although is working perfectly fine on my local system)

Can anybody help me out with an alternative solution without walk? Would be highly appreciated.

*edit*
Ok I got it. I can manually add the walk function such as:

```
'def walk(f):
                                   . as $in
                                 | if type == "object" then
                                 reduce keys_unsorted[] as $key
                                 ( {}; . + { ($key):  ($in[$key] | walk(f)) } ) | f
                                 elif type == "array" then map( walk(f) ) | f
                                 else f
                                 end; walk(if type=="object"
                                           and has("group")
                                           and (.group | type)=="array"
                                           and (.group | length)==1
                                           then .group = .group[0]
                                           else . end)'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could operate one level higher in the nesting hierarchy, and test for `"group"` being a key, then update accordingly `.group = .group[0]` instead of `. = .[0]`

```
jq 'walk(if type=="object"
          and has("group") 
          and (.group | type)=="array" 
          and (.group | length)==1 
          then .group = .group[0] 
          else . end)'
```

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks!

And thanks for the explanation!